# Rails 3 - How to fetch values from has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

**I have this models:**

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :infos, :title

  has_many :files
end

class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :desc, :file, :page_id, :title, :file_uid, :file_name

  dragonfly_accessor :file

  belongs_to :page
end
```

How can I get data from the Page controller?

**I'm trying this:**

```
def show
      @page = Page.find(params[:id])
      #@files = @page.attachment.find_by_name
      #@files = Attachment.order(:title)

      @files = @page.attachment.all


      respond_to do |format|
        format.html # show.html.erb
        format.json { render json: @page }
      end
end
```

In Attachment show view I just do

```
<%= @attachment.page.title %>
```

But when I try to get values from Page view or controller like that, I got the error: **undefined method `attachment'**

Answer (score 4):

It should be:

```
@files = @page.files
```

And you have to specify the class name of the association in `Page`:

```
has_many :files, class_name: 'Attachment'
```

Or you just use `has_many :attachments` in `Page`, then use:

```
@files = @page.attachments
```